# NPM pro-gallery, doesn't load images in live site

Tags: netlify, production

I am trying to use the gallery in production but I am having an issue that it doesn't load until I open my developer tools than all photos appear. Everything works fine on localhost, this only happens when the site is live.

[image: screen shot of gallery code]

Images are inserted from a list sorted in another file, everything loads on the localhost using GatsbyJS right away, but when I have it deployed to netlify the photos won't appear until I open the dev tools, and magically everything is good

Comment: Problem was caused by the way gatsby loads. Since with gatsby "window" is not available during server-side rendering, I had the innerWidth and innerHeight found on an eventListener for resize, was able to chance it to a useEffect to find the innerWidth and Height once the component mounted.